# Validate from Field

Tags: forms, validation

I don't know if this is the right forum for my question, and I mean no disrespect, but here goes. Will someone please direct me to where I can learn how to validate a text field on a form. I have searched the Internet for 2-hours and have not come up with a solution. I am new to Dreamweaver. I have the free trial version Dreamweaver Creative Cloud and it does not have the Spry features of the previous versions. I apologize for rambling, but I am so frustrated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)??

It has everything about PHP/HTML and CSS. Rather basic but you can expand from there